# Xcode File name too Long

Tags: xcode

/Users/qusai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TravelTranslator-hhsklkhmdsmuuzfkegzvfdfmmmtz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TravelTranslator.app make directory /Users/qusai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TravelTranslator-hhsklkhmdsmuuzfkegzvfdfmmmtz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/TravelTranslator.app/Frameworks: File name too long

I tried deleting derived data folder but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Did you mistakenly make a recursive copy of something in your project folder or create a recursive soft link? Or you have a typo in a build setting that's leading to the bad path.